# How to detect objects in a video opencv with Python?

Tags: python, opencv, frames

I have a video consisting of different objects such as square, rectangle , triangle. I somehow need to detect and show only square objects. So in each frame, if there is a square, it is fine but if there is a triangle or rectangle then it should display it. I am using background subtraction and I am able to detect all the three objects and create a bounding box around them. But I am not able to figure out how to display only square object.

Comment: Have you tried something, like [opencv official examples](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/squares.py)?

Comment: show us the code you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following algorithm:

-Perform Background subtraction, as you're doing currently

-enclose foreground in contours (using findContours(,,,) then drawContours(,,,) function)

-enclose obtained contours in bounding boxes (using boundingRect(,,,) function)

-if area of bounding box is approximately equal to that of enclosed contour, then the shape is a square or rectangle, not a triangle. 
(A large part of the box enclosing a triangle will lie outside the triangle)

-if boundingBox height is approximately equal to its width, then it is a square. (access height and width by Rect.height and Rect.width)

Answer (score 1):

How are your objects filled or just an outline?
In either case the approach I would take is to detect the vertices by finding the maximum gradient or just by the bounding box. The vertices will be on the bounding box. Once you have the vertices, you can say whether the object is a square or a rectangle just by finding the distances between the consecutive vertices.